# List filtering variant

Tags: c#, list, methods

Is there an easy way (maybe a method) of retrieving  an object  from a list depending on if one of its property matches the requested one?

For example, if I have `List<Animal>` and the `Animal` class has a property `Size`. How could I get the objects from a list with `Size=42`? It's like filtering but isn't there an easier and faster way of doing it? Insted of using `ICollectionView`.

```
public Animal getAnimalWithSize42 (List<Animal> animList)
{
    List<Animal> size42Animals = new List<Animal>
    foreach (Animal anim in animList)
    { 
        if(anim.Size==42)
       size42Animals.Add(anim);
    }
    return size42Animals;
}
```

Is this some kind of implemented function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ, that's generally the easiest way. Something like this maybe:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> getAnimalWithSize42(IEnumerable<Animal> animList)
{
    return animList.Where(animal => animal.Size == 42);
}
```

If you wanted to be slick - you could even let the caller pass in what they want to retrieve:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> getAnimalsMeetingCriteria(IEnumerable<Animal> animals, Func<Animal, bool> filter)
{
    return animals.Where(filter);
}
```

Make sure you add a reference to `System.Linq` in the file that needs to use this.

Comment: You probably meant to use `Where` instead of `First`? I think the OP wants to retrieve them all, not just the first one...

Comment: @PaoloTedesco yes you are right if we base the answer from the op question.. it should be.. `where`

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ:

```
return animList.Where(anim => anim.Size == 42);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ to do it.

```
List<Animal> size42Animals = animList.Where(anim => anim.Size == 42).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is ideal for this purpose:

```
public Animal getAnimalWithSize42 (List<Animal> animList)
{
    return animList.Where(a => a.Size == 42);
}
```